# Camelot-py not detecting two lines of text in one row

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-scraping, python-camelot

Scraping table data from a .PDF using Camelot-py, and it is not picking up stacked lines of text (refer to rows 9 and 10 below)

[image: 1 through 14]

[Rows 9 and 10 are void of text for account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrLnJ.png)

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#specify-table-areas

Here is the code I have in .ipynb format. The first block is for the first table that pulls as expected, the second is for page 9.

## Table

```
tables= camelot.read_pdf(r'C:\PDFFilePath', pages='9', line_scale=40)
    tables[0].to_csv(r'Loans&Leases')
    camelot.plot(tables[0], kind ='contour')
    plt.show()
```

Using MatPlotLib, I can see that Camelot is correctly detecting the table area/grid for page 9.

[plot table area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9dEX.png)

[plot grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv3xn.png)

Here is a Google Drive link to the PDF

[Call Report PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gq7AjC_kt3GAF9Ii65pf3b4LxWB57c8i/view?usp=sharing)

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share the original PDF if you can and the code you tried.

Comment: @anakin87 done, thank you very much for your interest and taking a look

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct.

If you try to type `tables[0].df`, this is the output, which is correct:

[image]

So, your problem, at the moment of exporting to CSV, is the line break (\n) in the 10th and 11th rows.

A solution can be the following code:

`tables= camelot.read_pdf(r'C:\PDFFilePath', pages='9', line_scale=40, strip_text='\n')`

With `strip_text`, you can strip unwanted characters (see [official documentation](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#strip-characters-from-text)).

Now, if you export the table to CSV, you get:
[image]